# Search for 2 specific letters followed by 4 numbers Regex

Tags: c#, regex, match

I need to check if a string begins with 2 specific letters and then is followed by any 4 numbers.

the 2 letters are "BR" so BR1234 would be valid so would BR7412 for example.

what bit of code do I need to check that the string is a match with the Regex in C#?

the regex I have written is below, there is probably a more efficient way of writing this (I'm new to RegEx)

```
[B][R][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Put `^` anchor: `^BR[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^BR\d{4}");
```

- `^` defines the start of the string (so there should be no other characters before BR)
- `BR` matches - well - BR
- `\d` is a digit (0-9)
- `{4}` says there must be exactly 4 of the previously mentioned group (`\d`)

You did not specify what is allowed to follow the four digits. If this should be the end of the string, add a `$`.

Usage in C#:

```
string matching = "BR1234";
string notMatching = "someOther";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^BR\d{4}");
bool doesMatch = regex.IsMatch(matching); // true
doesMatch = regex.IsMatch(notMatching); // false;
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the c# code to implement this would look like?

Comment: @JoeBW implement what specifically? To test if a string matches use the line from above (`Regex regex = ...`) and then you can test like `var doesMatch = regex.IsMatch("...your string...");`

Comment: Thanks, Do I need a reference/nuget for the class "Regex"

Comment: @JoeBW No it's part of the framework, decalred in System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. So `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` is enough. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
BR\d{4}
```

Some text to make answer at least 30 characters long :)

Comment: How about using those 30 characters for explanation?

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the c# code to implement this would look like?